# Why does this for loop keep going with out stopping?

Tags: arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, scanf

I have a program with a for loop outside the main function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void inputMaze(char maze[], int maxX, int maxY);

int main()
{
//Number of columns
int maxX= 0;
//Number of rows
int maxY= 0;

printf("Number of rows? ");
scanf("%d", &maxY);
printf("Number of columns? ");
scanf("%d", &maxX);
if(maxX*maxY>300){
    printf("Number of cells exceeds maximum!/n");
}
char maze[maxX][maxY];
inputMaze(maze,maxX, maxY);
return 0;
}

void inputMaze(char maze[], int maxX, int maxY){
int i;
for(i=0; i<maxY; i=i+1){
        printf("Input row %d ", i);
        scanf(" %c", &maze[i]);

}
}
```

The output gives me this:

```
Number of rows? 10
Number of columns? 10
Input row 0 S#####
Input row 1 Input row 2 Input row 3 Input row 4 Input row 5 Input row 6 D.....
Input row 7 Input row 8 Input row 9
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 11.526 s
Press any key to continue.
```

I don't want Input row 1 Input row 2.... to be printed like this. I'm trying to get it so that it prints Input row i on a new line each time and the user can input a new line. I think the problem might be to do with the scanf storing to a 2D array. I would like to be so that one line in the maze array is written in at a time and then each element in the line is taken up by one letter but I can't seem to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem lies in this statement

> scanf(" %c", &maze[i]);

You are trying to read by character by character which is wrong. You have to read maxY rows as strings. I have produced the working code here.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void inputMaze(char maze[], int maxX, int maxY);

int main()
{
//Number of columns
int maxX= 0;
//Number of rows
int maxY= 0;

printf("Number of rows? ");
scanf("%d", &maxY);
printf("Number of columns? ");
scanf("%d", &maxX);
if(maxX*maxY>300){
    printf("Number of cells exceeds maximum!/n");
}
char maze[maxX][maxY];
inputMaze(maze,maxX, maxY);
return 0;
}

void inputMaze(char maze[], int maxX, int maxY){
int i;
for(i=0; i<maxY; i=i+1){
        printf("Input row %d\n", i);
        scanf("%s", &maze[i]);

}
}
```

If you need to more assistance, feel free to comment.

Comment: Thanks! So basically you just changed %c to %s and this automatically adds the string as an array? How come the program doesn't crash/array run out of space if I make maxX and maxY 6 and enter a 7-character string? EDIT: What does it look like in an array? When I add a for loop that prints %c in maze[i] it just seems to print the first symbol of each line.

Comment: can you run it in ideone and post link here? I am ready to help

Comment: https://ideone.com/8Eyovq here you go. You should learn how to use 2-d arrays. http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pass-2d-array-parameter-c/ Still if you need any help, feel free to comment.

Comment: That's a great help :)